# Code for writing data is lagging as data grows (15-second delay) C#

Tags: c#

I have a code that is logging data received through an arduino device. The device outputs a couple times per second so I am expecting at least 1-value per second but once I start hitting the 500 sometimes 1000 point mark I start getting intermittent data points with up to 15-seconds in-between. I am not really an expert in handling memory and efficiency so I am confident my code is doing something wrong or inefficiently:

My 2 suspects are:

- The GUI is slowing down everything. (I do notice the GUI freeze up a lot more as time goes on)
- My TemperatureReadings Class is doing something funky?

=== REFERENCE CLASS ===

```
internal class TemperatureReading
    {
        internal double[] fullTempArray; //Normally size 50.
        internal DateTime timeStamp;

        public TemperatureReading(double refProbe, params double[] temps)
        {
            this.timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            this.fullTempArray = new double[temps.Length + 1];
            Array.Copy(temps, fullTempArray, temps.Length);
            this.fullTempArray[fullTempArray.Length - 1] = refProbe; //Last value from reference.
        }

        public string generateTextString()
        {
            string parsedTemps = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < this.fullTempArray.Length; i++)
            {
                parsedTemps += fullTempArray[i].ToString();
                parsedTemps += ",";
            }
            string parsedString = String.Format(timeStamp.ToString("H:mm:ss:f") + ", " + parsedTemps);
            return parsedString;
        }
}
```

=== END CLASS ===

So that's the code that will be called in the form below:

=== FORM CODE ===

StreamWriter fileWriter;

```
    private void updateTemps()
    {
        //Is called after every data-received is parsed and stored into the probeArray
        // PROBEARRAY is a custom class that cointains 14 internal variables
        // AFTER UPDATING all numbers, check if it is logging (calibrating) and log it if it is. 
        //Will update display based on current values of the probeArray.Temp values which gets parsed every time data is received.
        //Will also update colors / backgrounds depending on things
        for (int i = 0; i < probeArray.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (Control c in sensorTempPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (c.Name.Length > 2) //some controls have name "", some have their code "A2, A4, B6 etc..."
                {
                    if (c.Name.Substring(c.Name.Length - 2) == probeArray[i].Name) //match by name (Location).
                    {
                        string newLbl = String.Format("{0:0.00}", probeArray[i].Temp);
                        if ((probeArray[i].Temp > 149.5) && !isLogging) //isLogging will show resistance so it will always be over 150.
                        {
                            newLbl = "HI";
                        } else if ((probeArray[i].Temp < -19.5) && !isLogging)
                        {
                            newLbl = "LO";
                        }
                        Invoke(new Action(() => c.Text = newLbl)); //Synchronous code to update GUI

                        if (probeArray[i].isHigh && !probeArray[i].isIgnored)
                        {
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.ForeColor = Color.Crimson)); //Will change the "highest" value text to Red
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold)));
                        }
                        else if (probeArray[i].isLow && !probeArray[i].isIgnored)
                        {
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.ForeColor = Color.Blue));
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.ForeColor = Color.Black));
                            Invoke(new Action(() => c.Font = new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Regular)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (topSensorsEnabled)
            {
                updateTopSensors();
            }
        }
        if (isGraphing)
        {
            passGraphData();
        }
        addDataSetToLog();
        averageProbeValues();
    }


    private void addDataSetToLog()
    {
        TemperatureReading newRead = new TemperatureReading(refTemp, probeTemps);
        temperatureReadingsLog.Add(newRead);

        if (isLogging)
        {
            saveDatatoLogFile(newRead);
        }
    }

    private void saveDatatoLogFile(TemperatureReading newLine)
    {
        fileWriter.WriteLine(newLine.generateTextString());
    }
```

=== END FORM CODE ===

Comment: The TemperatureReading class is doing a log of data copying just to write to the log. You could do something more efficient working on "probeTemps" directly in addDataSetToLog() / saveDatatoLogFile(). How big are the arrays - do they keep getting bigger ? PS - IO is one of the slowest things you can possibly do.

Comment: I do keep the array in memory because the user can technically "graph data" without logging it (so I need the data points for the graph). 
I am not sure about IO, as I said I consider myself a beginner so if you could point me to what alternatives there are (I did not add it by choice, it was added automatically with some functions I use)

Comment: **(1)** Allocating array memory one slot at a time when adding reading could be slow if you do that in a loop a lot of time.  **(2)** Invoking multiple small actions on the UI will also be very slow. You should at most do a single `Invoke` per iteration and if you have a lot of reading per seconds, maybe even batch them or skip them. **(3)** Use a profiler to know where you spend time.

Comment: Instead of storing your data in a `double[]` which you re-allocate every time a new data point comes in, store it in a `List<double>`. Internally, that list will allocate an array as a buffer and re-allocate the buffer only periodically as needed instead of every time an element is added.

Comment: GUI freeze?  Could this be a garbage collection issue?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Hi Loren, it might be, how could I fix it if it is? could you link me some details please?

Comment: I will try that, @EricJ., Do you mean instead of Array.Copy I should just say internalList = methodInputList ?

Comment: @dvd.Void You address garbage collection issues by minimizing garbage creation.  In extreme cases everything is preallocated and the important code allocates **nothing**.  Look at Eric J.'s comment for an example of reducing garbage creation.